# Why creating an empty cart via REST API requires parameters for quote address for this customer account?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, cart, rest-api, magento2.3.3

I'm using Magento 2.3.3. Normally, calling this [endpoint](https://magento.redoc.ly/2.3.7-admin/tag/cartsmine/#operation/quoteCartManagementV1CreateEmptyCartForCustomerPost) will return customer's quote ID. But for this specific user, I got this error as a response:

```json
{
    "message": "One or more input exceptions have occurred.",
    "errors": [{
        "message": "\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.",
        "parameters": {
            "fieldName": "firstname"
        }
    }, {
        "message": "\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.",
        "parameters": {
            "fieldName": "lastname"
        }
    }, {
        "message": "\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.",
        "parameters": {
            "fieldName": "street"
        }
    }, {
        "message": "\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.",
        "parameters": {
            "fieldName": "city"
        }
    }, {
        "message": "\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.",
        "parameters": {
            "fieldName": "telephone"
        }
    }, {
        "message": "\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.",
        "parameters": {
            "fieldName": "postcode"
        }
    }, {
        "message": "\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.",
        "parameters": {
            "fieldName": "countryId"
        }
    }],
    "trace": "#0 /vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php(622): Magento\\Customer\\Model\\ResourceModel\\AddressRepository->save(Object(Magento\\Customer\\Model\\Data\\Address))\n#1 /vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php(271): Magento\\Quote\\Model\\QuoteManagement->_prepareCustomerQuote(Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Interceptor))\n#2 [internal function]: Magento\\Quote\\Model\\QuoteManagement->createEmptyCartForCustomer(792)\n#3 /vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#4 /vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(188): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\Rest\\Request\\Proxy))\n#5 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#6 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#7 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#8 /generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#9 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(137): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#10 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(261): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#11 /pub/index.php(40): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#12 {main}"
}
```

The formatted trace:

```
#0 /vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php(622): Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\AddressRepository->save(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Address))
#1 /vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php(271): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->_prepareCustomerQuote(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor))
#2 [internal function]: Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->createEmptyCartForCustomer(792)
#3 /vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(188): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Proxy))
#5 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#7 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 /generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#9 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(137): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(261): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#11 /pub/index.php(40): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#12 {main}
```

Other customer accounts don't have this problem. Just this account. How should I debug this problem?